# How to implement If condition in Cucumber Scenarios

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a specific scenario as follows:

```
 if (element shows up on UI)
  validate it
 else
   no harm done; move on...
```

If I know upfront if the element shows up or not, I can frame two different scenarios, when the element shows up and when not.
But, in this case, it may or may not be present. If it is present, it should function as expected.

Any suggestions on how this can be implemented in a Cucumber scenario(s) ?
I am using Cucumber-jvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate scenarios, you just need to be able to make sure you setup the preconditions to assume one scenario vs the other.

In general, you should not be implementing a conditional inside a single scenario, because your intent is to test two scenarios.